# TextView doesn't change its text

Tags: java, android, textview

Hello I have a problem with TextView. Here's my code

```
final TextView username = (TextView) _v.findViewById(R.id.username);
final LinearLayout linear7 = (LinearLayout) _v.findViewById(R.id.linear7);
final TextView date = (TextView) _v.findViewById(R.id.date);
final TextView msg = (TextView) _v.findViewById(R.id.msg);
final TextView username2 = (TextView) _v.findViewById(R.id.username);
final LinearLayout linear72 = (LinearLayout) _v.findViewById(R.id.linear7);
final TextView date2 = (TextView) _v.findViewById(R.id.date);
final TextView msg2 = (TextView) _v.findViewById(R.id.msg);
final LinearLayout linear999 = (LinearLayout) _v.findViewById(R.id.linear999);
final LinearLayout linear9992 = (LinearLayout) _v.findViewById(R.id.linear9992);

username.setText(map1.get((int)_position).get("name").toString());
msg.setText(map1.get((int)_position).get("msg").toString());
date.setText(map1.get((int)_position).get("date").toString());
username2.setText(username.getText().toString());
msg2.setText(msg.getText().toString());
date2.setText(date.getText().toString());
```

As you can see, username2 should have the same text as username. But, it just has the text that I've given for it in designer. Please help.

Comment: note that you make the same mistake for username, msg, linear7 and date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
final TextView username = (TextView) _v.findViewById(R.id.username);
final TextView username2 = (TextView) _v.findViewById(R.id.username);
```

They have same view id. You have to change username2 view id.

Comment: Thanks. I've just noticed that i'm so stupid ;P but thanks for the quick reply ^^

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the id of yout `TextView` Its the same. change it to the id that connects on the 2nd `TextView`

```
 final TextView msg = (TextView) _v.findViewById(R.id.msg);

 final TextView msg2 = (TextView) _v.findViewById(R.id.msg); <--- change this ID
```

Answer (score 1):

I am simply combining two correct issues mentioned by two different users (Maxitors and Mike) into one answer:

The Textviews of both pairs are the same element

- Username and Username2 have an id R.id.username
- msg and msg2 have an id R.id.msg

This causes them to refer to the same element whenever you make function calls on them. For example setting the text of username2 to the text of username will have no noticeable effect as you just set the text of the element R.id.username to itself.

To fix this issue you need to assign Username2 and msg2 to the correct id's whatever they may be. (Looking at your naming scheme i suspect them to be R.id.username2 and R.id.msg2 )

Answer (score -1):

I think you can not change the text, because you declared it as a final variable. In what context stands this codeblock that you need to declare it final. Try it without would my first advice.

Comment: The text is not declared as a final variable, only the `TextView`. Nothing wrong with the `TextView` being final.